# /bin is missed in JDK

Tags: java, linux, maven, bin

I'm trying to install Maven on RH7 but I'm getting the error:

**NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE**

The thing is that I have Java is already installed and `$JAVA_HOME` is defined correctly (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64`), but it has to be added to `$PATH` as `$JAVA_HOME/bin` and I don't have `bin` in `$JAVA_HOME`, the only directory I have there is `jre`.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have bin in $JAVA_HOME, the only directory I have there is jre.

That almost certainly means you haven't actually got the JDK, just the jre, despite the folder name (hence the Maven error.)

Try installing / extracting the full JDK somewhere else if necessary (either by adding an external RPM and grabbing it, or just downloading it manually if you want the simple approach), then point `JAVA_HOME` to that directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are right. JDK has not been installed.